# Interviewer asked me to submit the solution of a problem after the interview

Tags: interviewing

I recently had a technical interview. It went decent I suppose. I could answer lots of questions, but he asked a coding question, which took the whole interview for me to solve. He asked if he should change the question, but I declined and asked if I could continue with that. And since I couldn't solve the question until the end, he asked me to submit the solution over email. And within around 15 minutes after the interview, I solved that and submitted it.

So I wanted to know whether my solution submission would be judged after the interview was over.

It was the second round of interviews.

Comment: It's impossible for us to say. How your interviewer treats your submitted solution is entirely up to them.

Comment: Of course it's subjective to each interviewer. But I mean, in general, is it a good sign or a bad one? Like if any interviewer asks you to submit the solution over email after the interview because you couldn't solve it at that time, does it mean that you performed poorly in the interview?

Comment: I've run lots of interviews and I've never asked a candidate to email me a solution. I don't know under what scenarios that makes sense.

Comment: @GregoryCurrie I presume it's in India, and at times what happens that either the interviewer wants to sound positive by asking the solution over email, or are simply not straightforward enough to mention that the interview is over. These sort of "follow-up" is a lame way of finding an "exit" from the interview.

Comment: If you weren't still in the running, he probably wouldn't bother asking for the submission. Unless they themselves don't know and need a hint :)

Comment: I had an interviewer go look up my GitHub and comment on some not-so-ideal code I had there, and ask me to improve it and send the update in an email. I got hired in the end. Not sure what that changes.

Answer (score 5):

It *may* mean many things:

- They are actually interested in seeing how you approach a problem (and not just the solution). So, the follow up might be actually getting checked. Hence, your submission will actually make positive effect.
- They are interested in seeing the solution, but you took more time than expected. They might be happy that you worked through the problem, but they might be not satisfied on the fact that you overshoot the time. Your submission afater interview will not make any difference, it's neutral.
- They did not want to see the solution after the interview was over, but due to some reason (politeless, for example), they asked you to send the solution offline so that you do not feel bad. In this case, again, the result can be neutral.
- They were anticipating that the moment you get out, you'll get help (mentors , online forums etc.) and create the solution. Now, as you said, you were able to solve and share the solution in next 15 mins, that will kind of reinforce that thought - and will likely create a negative impression.
- If the solution is not clear, or of poor quality (or, not as expected), it may have a negative effect, since the option to converse is not there anymore.

and many other options.

**Which one actually happens in your case - we cannot predict**. Just let it go, don't bank on it. If it's a positive turn, good, if not, there's nothing you can do about it. Good luck.

Comment: The submission may also have a negative effect if the solution is poor.

Comment: @GregoryCurrie True that, let me add that one also.

Answer (score 0):

If they want to fail you right away, perhaps, they would have not asked you to send them a complete solution after the interview.

As they ask you to submit a solution after the interview, it could be that your approach is so new and interesting to them, and they simply want to see if it actually works. If your final solution is significantly better than theirs (for example: yours has better time and space complexity), then they will appreciate yours very much, and that may help to move you to the next round of interviews.

Please note that, for live coding interviews, sometimes,  the interviewers could extend the interviews for another 10 or 15 minutes at the end to see if the candidates can solve the problems (especially when the candidates are doing pretty well during the interview) .

So, you should wait and see what their reply to your solution is.

In data structures and algorithms, there may always be fun, exciting, and more efficient solutions that people are not aware of. :-)

---

Another scenario is that the interviewer wanted to end the interview sharply at the end as you both ran out of time because he may have another interview lined up with another candidate, or a big important meeting with his boss. So, he had to end your interview at that point. But, he wanted to give you some extra time to submit a complete solution for him to review as he may like your strategy to solve this problem.

Or, it could be that the interviewer may simply want to be polite and asked you to submit the complete solution for your interview record.

---

We don't know exactly what the interviewer was thinking.

In the meantime, perhaps, you should simply enjoy those interviews and learn something positive from them. For every passed or failed interview, you can always learn something from it to prepare for future interviews. If you don't get a job with this company, there are always other companies to look forward to. Keep applying for new jobs.

Answer (score 0):

By judged I'll assume you mean "considered".

The interviewer asked you to submit it, so my guess is that yes, they'll consider it.

Answer (score -1):

Short answer : No

Long answer : there are many points to judge you during the technical testing. I list factors as below :

1, Have you completely understand the testing requirements, what they want you to do

2, have you discuss with interviewer what you think, and your solution.

3, When you can not solve the problem, what you behave, do you show stressful and out of patient.

4, Have you ask for help when you can not solve the problem.

5, Have you solved the testing.(this part is higher priority of course)